# Translation of Hebrew letters

Tags: hebrew, translation, aleph-bet-letters

I hope that this is not off-topic for this forum.  If so, please let me know and I will delete it.

I'm trying to understand the meaning of these letters which I believe are Hebrew.  Can someone who is familiar with the language please provide a translation?  I realize that it's a relatively poor image but it's the best I can come up with at this time.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Image of Hebrew letters]

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more context? The second word is Moshe as in the Hebraic form for the name Moses.

Comment: I would guess the first word is יחיאל = Jehiel, another name

Comment: @JoelK it looks like ידיצל ??

Comment: @Dov I saw it in a photo and was curious about what it meant.

Comment: @dov I agree that’s what it looks like at first glance, but obviously that’s meaningless. And the OP said the picture is of poor quality. So I’m guessing, based on the second word being a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like it says השם לצידי (Hashem is on my side/next to me), but with the letters in reverse order for some reason.

Comment: I’ve seen several Hebrew tattoos where the letter were in reverse order. The last one I saw was supposed to be one of G-d’s names, but was printed backwards.

Comment: @Menachem Now that you mention it, the OP's picture does look an awful lot like a tattoo.

Comment: Could be  a simple mixup by someone who doesn't realize Hebrew is spelled right-to-left.